# Python NameError: It is not seeing array name

Tags: python-3.x

```
from urllib.request import urlopen


def fetch_words():
    with urlopen('http://undisclosedServer.com/c/t.txt') as test_page:
        test_page_words = []
        for line in test_page:
            line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()

        for word in line_words:
            test_page_words.append(word)


    for word in test_page_words:
        print(word)
```

It generates `NameError: name 'test_page_words' is not defined`
I am not sure why it is not able to see the array name.

Comment: Is the last loop `for word in test_page_words` inside the function fetch_words or outside it? Fix your indentation accordingly.

Comment: In what line is the error?

Comment: Updated indentation and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last loop:

```
for word in test_page_words:
    print(word)
```

is outside the `fetch_words()` function inside which variable `test_page_words` is defined. Placing this loop inside `fetch_words()` function should fix the issue.